# How to use require_once() multiple and connect to different database in the same page?

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to connect to different database in the same page and select two times . but it seems not working and i get just one database and select working! this is my code

```
<?php 
require_once ('../connect_upevent.php');
require_once ('../connect_events.php');


$select_upevent="SELECT * FROM upevent";
$result_upevent=mysqli_query($con,$select_upevent);

$select_events="SELECT img_name , title , LEFT(`content` , 540)  as `content`,date, id FROM events";
$result_events=mysqli_query($con,$select_events);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my while()

```
                        <?php while ($row_upevent = mysqli_fetch_array($result_upevent)) {   ?>                     
                    <li> 
                        <h4><?php echo $row_upevent['title'] ?></h4> 
                        <div class="dt-sc-two-third column first event-index-float">
                            <img src="images/event/<?php echo $row_upevent['img_name'] ?>" alt="" title="">
                            <p><?php echo $row_upevent['content'] ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dt-sc-one-third column event-index-float">
                            <div class="venue">
                                <h5>location</h5>
                                <p><?php echo $row_upevent['place'] ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="details">
                                <h5>time</h5>
                                <p><?php echo $row_upevent['date'] ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
```

my while() #2

```
                        <?php while ($row_events = mysqli_fetch_array($result_events)) {   ?>                     
                    <!--blog starts-->
                    <div class="dt-sc-one-half column first animate" data-animation="fadeInLeft" data-delay="300">
                        <article class="blog-entry">
                            <div class="entry-thumb">
                                <a href="event-detail.php?post=<?php echo $row_events['id'] ?>"><img src="images/event/<?php echo $row_events['img_name'] ?>" alt="" title=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="entry-details">
                                <div class="entry-title">
                                    <h2><a href="event-detail.php?post=<?php echo $row_events['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row_events['title'] ?></a></h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="entry-body">
                                    <p><?php echo $row_events['content'].'&nbsp;[ ... ]' ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="entry-footer">
                                    <a href="event-detail.php?post=<?php echo $row_events['id'] ?>" class="read-more">read more<span class="fa fa-caret-left"></span> </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <!--blog ends-->
                    <?php } ?>
```

so how can i get it work !?

Comment: use different connection object like :- $con1 and $con2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two connection with different object

> connect_upevent.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection 1
$con1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

> connect_events.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection 2
$con2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

> And use these connection like that

```
<?php 
require_once ('../connect_upevent.php');
require_once ('../connect_events.php');


$select_upevent="SELECT * FROM upevent";
$result_upevent=mysqli_query($con1,$select_upevent);

$select_events="SELECT img_name , title , LEFT(`content` , 540)  as `content`,date, id FROM events";
$result_events=mysqli_query($con2,$select_events);

mysqli_close($con1);
mysqli_close($con2);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting successively and have same names for both database instances. You should rather make different connection objects. Just name them differently.

```
<?php 
require_once ('../connect_upevent.php'); // $con_upevent
require_once ('../connect_events.php'); // $con_events


$select_upevent="SELECT * FROM upevent";
$result_upevent=mysqli_query($con_upevent, $select_upevent);

$select_events="SELECT img_name , title , LEFT(`content` , 540)  as `content`,date, id FROM events";
$result_events=mysqli_query($con_events, $select_events);

mysqli_close($con_upevent);
mysqli_close($con_events);
?>
```

or connect to one, make query, connect to second and make query

```
<?php 
require_once ('../connect_upevent.php');
require_once ('../connect_events.php');


$select_upevent="SELECT * FROM upevent";
$result_upevent=mysqli_query($con_upevent, $select_upevent);

$select_events="SELECT img_name , title , LEFT(`content` , 540)  as `content`,date, id FROM events";
$result_events=mysqli_query($con_events, $select_events);

mysqli_close($con_upevent);
mysqli_close($con_events);
?>
<?php 
// Connect to first DB
require_once ('../connect_upevent.php');

$select_upevent="SELECT * FROM upevent";
$result_upevent=mysqli_query($con,$select_upevent);

mysqli_close($con);

// Connect to second DB
require_once ('../connect_events.php');

$select_events="SELECT img_name , title , LEFT(`content` , 540)  as `content`,date, id FROM events";
$result_events=mysqli_query($con,$select_events);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to see the content of the included files:

- connect_upevent.php
- connect_events.php

But i guess, the problem is the following:
You work with the same instance `$con`.

So the first time you declare `$con` in the file "connect_upevent.php" and then it gets overwritten in the file "connect_events.php"

You should make two instances in the included files. Like:

`$con_upevent` and `$con_events`.

Otherwise, the `$con` variable is overwritten by the "connect_events.php" file